# I want to Add One Image over another .the first One I am getting from youtube as thumbnail and second i am taking from my drawable folder

Tags: android, youtube

I want to Add One Image over another .the first One I am getting from youtube as thumbnail and second i am taking from my drawable folder.the aim is to add a play button like Image Over the image I am getting from the youtube video thumbnail.

//part of source code

```
final VedioDataSet record3 = imageslist.get(j);
ImageView img3 = new ImageView(VideoScreen.this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = layoutParams;
params3.weight = 1f;
params3.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
                                img3.setLayoutParams(params3);
                                img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                img3.setTag(record3.getYoutubeimg());

                                img3.setLayoutParams(params3);
                                img3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                img3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_btn1);

                                imageloader.DisplayImage(record3.getYoutubeimg(), VideoScreen.this, img3);
                                hlinearlayout.addView(img3);

                                playVideo(img3,record3);
```

Comment: I don't see a question here.  What problem are you seeing?

Comment: i want to add another Image over this Image and don't Know how to add that...

Answer (score 0):

define two ImageView one over another and load the images accordingly !! and for placing ImageView in that fashion you can use FrameLayout or RelativeLayout but FrameLayout is recomemnded